# How to set slack reminder for private channel

Tags: slack

I am able to set slack reminder using `/remind #public-channel` but for private channel there is no option.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is true. You may want to check out some of the many Slack apps for an alternative that also works in private channels

Answer (score 144):

Found a solution for this. In case of a private-channel you can use slack inbuilt `/remind` command in following way:

> /remind @channel every weekday at 2pm to start daily standup.

Here you can use either `@here` (to remind only online people) or `@channel` (remind everyone in the channel irrespective they are online).

This was a nifty trick I used with my private slack channel. Wont find it on slack documentation but it works.

Comment: It looks like slack has since disabled this and it's no longer possible :(

Comment: Doesn't work "can't find user @private-channel" at least on the free tier.

Comment: Its not @ private-channel its @ channel even inside a private channel - try this it will work.

Comment: I get "I’m sorry! You can’t set reminders for others in this workspace. You can remind yourself to remind them, though." any ideas .. ?

Comment: @ Pikachu-go Thanks so much, your answer really helped me. @channel actually works for private channels.

Answer (score 81):

I was able to set the reminder for the private channel by treating the name as a public channel as such :

Channel name : `@private-channel`

```
/remind #private-channel at 9AM every weekday to Start standup
```

Using `#private-channel` did not show the channel as an option in the list, but after submitting the reminder, it works

Comment: `#` prefix matters I think

Comment: This answer is the correct one. It still works the normal way - it just looks like it's not going to because it doesn't appear in the channel list as you type.

Comment: correct, private channel names wont pop up as you type because it's private, which is smart since it prevents non-members from seeing the group name exists, such as #private-things-we-hate-about-the-boss ;)

Comment: Any idea about how can we remove `Reminder:` prefix from the output of the reminder?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the private channel:
/remind @here to “send cost report” at 9AM every weekday

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slack workflows to post a scheduled message in a private channel.
Start by tapping the lightning icon and search for "Create a workflow". It's straightforward from there